# How to create Thumbnail Image in PHP without loosing its Original Quality using GD Library

Tags: php, gd, thumbnails

```
if(isset($_POST["insert"]))
   {
      foreach($_FILES as $imgfile)
      {
        $tmp_name = $imgfile['tmp_name'];
        $type = $imgfile['type'];
        $name = $imgfile['name']; //name of original image
        $size = $imgfile['size'];

        if (file_exists($tmp_name))
        {
         if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name))
            {
                $target="realimage/";
                $target .= basename($_FILES['image']['name']); //path of original image
                $file = fopen($tmp_name,'r');
                $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));
                fclose($file);
                $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$target);
            }
                $extension=  explode(".", $target);
                $extension=$extension[count($extension)-1]; //gives the image extension
                $maxwidth=400;
                $maxheight=200;
                switch($extension) {
                    case 'gif':
                        $tmpimg = imagecreatefromgif($target);
                        break;
                    case 'jpg':
                        $tmpimg = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
                        break;
                    case 'png':
                        $tmpimg = imagecreatefrompng($target);
                        break;
                }               
                list($width,$height)=getimagesize($target);
                if($width > $height)
                {
                    $thumb_width=$maxwidth;
                    $thumb_height=  intval($height*$thumb_width/$width);
                }
                else
                {
                    $thumb_height= $maxheight;
                    $thumb_width=intval($width*$thumb_height/$height);
                }
                $dest_x = intval(($maxwidth - $thumb_width) / 2);
                $dest_y = intval(($maxheight - $thumb_height) / 2);

                $newimg=  imagecreatetruecolor($maxwidth,$maxheight);


imagecopyresampled($newimg,$tmpimg,$dest_x,$dest_y,0,0,$thumb_width,$thumb_height,$width,$height);


               imagejpeg($newimg,"thumbimage/$name",100);
        } 
        }
        }
```

The code is like this 
1) I am uploading an Image in the folder "realimage" .
2) I want to display a resized image of the realimage on my website . For that I hav created a folder "thumbimage" which stores the thumbnail image of the original.

The code does create Thumbnails for the images which are larger than the specified thumbnail width and height, but the quality Looses and I get blur Images. I want the Image quality to be same as the original image , just the size should be small then the original.

I have got another problem as well, when I upload an Image smaller than the specified Thumbnail Width & Height , then the image does not fit into the area and fills just some part of the area leaving other area black.

Help Me in Creating Ideal Thumbnail meeting all the scenarios.

Comment: thumbnail is using for showing small size preview of the original image and why do you need to make it of original size and quality,,

Comment: @VaisakhPc -- I dont want to make it original size... I just want to preserve its Quality ,,,so that the image looks the same as original ,, but just in thumbnail format

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$type = exif_imagetype($pathToImages);

$width = imagesx($img);

$height = imagesy($img);

// calculate thumbnail size

if ($width >= $height) {

    //If width is greater than height

    $new_width = $thumbWidth;

    $new_height = floor($height * ($thumbWidth / $width));

} else {

    //If height is greater than width

    $new_height = $thumbWidth;

    $new_width = floor($width * ($thumbWidth / $height));

}

// create a new temporary image

// echo $new_height;

$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

  imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);    

// save thumbnail into a file
switch($type) {

    case 1 : 
        imagegif($tmp_img, $pathToThumbs . $file_name,90);
        break;
    case 2 :            
        imagejpeg($tmp_img, $pathToThumbs . $file_name,90);
        break;
    case 3 :                           
        imagepng($tmp_img, $pathToThumbs . $file_name,90);
        break;
    case 6 :            
        imagewbmp($tmp_img, $pathToThumbs . $file_name,90);
        break;
}
```

Comment: I tried it ...It still keeps the blank space in the image , i need the thumbnail image to occupy all space without stretching the image

Comment: You can set width of image = width of content/(10) or 20/ or 30 to fill 10 or 20 or 30 picture in 1 row

Comment: Not the solution i am looking for